# C++ Qt QGraphicsView: Remembering the position of scrollbars after reload

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following problem with scrollbars in graphics view. My application takes a PDF file and creates (in some way) a `QImage` out of it. The `QImage` is then converted to `QPixmap`, which is used to create a `QGraphicsScene` and from the `QGraphicsScene` I create a `QGraphicsView`. The `QGraphicsView` is added to the central widget and displayed.

The code looks approximately like this

```
QImage image;
image = loadImage(path);

QPixmap pixmap;
pixmap.convertFromImage(image);

scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
scene->addPixmap(pixmap);

view = new QGraphicsView(scene);

textEdit = new QTextEdit(this)
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(view);
layout->addWidget(textEdit);
QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
widget->setLayout(layout);
setCentralWidget(widget);
```

In the application, the `view` gets updated every time the PDF file changes. Now the problem is that the thing, which is in the PDF file, can also change in size and the scrollbars get messed up. I want the scrollbars after update to be in a position, such that I will see the same part of the PDF file as I saw before the update.

Can you give me some advice on how to accomplish this? I've searched for this issue, but nothing has worked in my case so far (I could have also be doing something wrong).

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: You shouldn't post your code as an answer. Edit your question instead. There is strange things in your code. You're trying to get scrollbar positions before you create the view. Obviously this doesn't work because the view is not created yet. How do you use that code? Are you trying to create separate view for each pixmap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before changing the view's contents remember scrollbar positions using `view->horizontalScrollBar()->value()` and `view->verticalScrollBar()->value()`.

After changing reset previous values using `setValue(int)`.

It's bad that you didn't provide any code that you have tried to use to accomplish this so I can't tell you what were you doing wrong.

Here is an example:

```
int pos_x = view->horizontalScrollBar()->value();
int pos_y = view->verticalScrollBar()->value();
pixmap_item->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(new_image));
view->horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(pos_x);
view->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(pos_y);
```

Here `pixmap_item` is the stored result of `scene->addPixmap(pixmap)`. It has `QGraphicsPixmapItem*` type.

Comment: Well, I've tried this. But I think that this doesn't work because the previous scrollbar value doesn't have the be the correct one after the update. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: It depends on the viewport size (which depends on the pixmap size). If pixmaps gets smaller, maximal values of scrollbars also become smaller. But scrollbars will get the closest possible value. So it should work. If you can use scrollbars to manually set the desired position, you must be able to do the same using `setValue`. Note that, for example, if the picture is smaller than the view, the picture will always be displayed in the center of the view and scrollbars will not appear at all.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the code, but it behaves strangely.

```
QImage image;
image = loadImage(path);

QPixmap pixmap;
pixmap.convertFromImage(image);

scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
scene->addPixmap(pixmap);

int hsbv = -1;
int vsbv = -1;

if (view != NULL) {
  hsbv = view->horizontalScrollBar()->value();
  vsbv = view->verticalScrollBar()->value();
}     

view = new QGraphicsView(scene);

textEdit = new QTextEdit(this)
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(view);
layout->addWidget(textEdit);
QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
widget->setLayout(layout);
setCentralWidget(widget);

view->horizontalScrollBar()->setVealue(hsbv);
view->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(vsbv);
```

When I print out the `view->horizontalScrollBar()->value()` at the end, I always get 83 and I get 479 for the `view->verticalScrollBar()->value()`, which is very wierd, but when I print `hsbv` and `vsbv` I get reasonable numbers.

Comment: In the past I've had to delay the calls to QScrollBar::setValue() until after the view has already been shown, in order to get the expected results -- that's because QScrollBar clamps the passed-in value to be in its valid [min, max] range, and before the view is shown, that range is not necessarily set correctly.  I worked around this by doing a QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(RestoreScrollBarValues()) from showEvent(), and doing the setValues() calls in the RetoreScrollBarValues() slot.